# How to prevent typescript compiler from using shorthand object property names?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to compile my typescript to JS but to have it not use short hand object names

`{a,b,c}`
to
`{a:a, b:b, c:c}`

is this possible?

Comment: Lower the EcmaScript version you're targeting. But why?

Comment: It's kinda hard to explain but the compiler version of rhinojs doesn't support it. I tried targeting ES3 and it still outputs the same for me.